# insights/page_fans_city/lifetime only returns some cities

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm calling `/insights/page_fans_city/lifetime` in Graph API and it seems to only return a small subset of cities.  I can't find a method for why those cities are chosen.

More importantly, I can't page to the next set of cities. That is, I can't get a complete list.

Does anyone know of a way to get `/insights/page_fans_city/lifetime` to return more cities?  Or to page through them?

Answer (score 1):

> Facebook Insights lets you see geographic and demographic data for people that have liked a Page or installed an app. Location data is based on the geographic location of each person as determined by their browser IP address and is limited to the top **20 countries and cities**. All other demographic information is aggregated and non-personally identifiable.

From [Insights FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/).

Comment: Thanks.  I already read this and understood this.  I was asking if anyone had found a way to get past this.

Comment: @dwenr What good would the limit be if you could just bypass it?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to bypass it.  Facebook used to provide their entire city list as a downloadable file.  Now we are forced to use endless wasteful Graph calls.  I could help both myself and facebook if I had a local copy.  That's all I'm asking for.